# libreoffice writer all blank menu entries after a few minutes use

Tags: libreoffice

Has anyone encountered this problem?

LibreOffice 5.2.2 (Writer) shows all blanks in the drop-down (main) menus, everything from File through to Help. Those headings are there, just the drop-downs are blank. Can I fix this?

Using Ubuntu Unity 16.04.1.LTS 
Same effect now in Mint 18

Comment: what is the version? rather old problem, so did you fix it in the meantime?